# 32 bit libraries not detected by locate command

Tags: linux, glassfish, debian, i386

So I've been trying to update my glass fish server, yet i need to get my 32bit libraries to work.

The issue is that I added the i386 architecture `**dpkg --add-achitecture i386**`, then i installed the packages I was asked after I updated "apt-get update". The libraries now reside in  `**/usr/lib/gnu-linux-i386**`.

> dpkg --add-architecture i386
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install ....

But when I run `**locate libjpeg.so**` for example, i don't get the i386 libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `locate -u` as root to update the cache after installing a package. `locate` doesn't scan the live filesystem each time you run the command, it uses a database that's updated every so often.

Comment: it's rather "updatedb" on debian, but you were right about the cache that needs to be updated. Thanks for your help